# count JSON objects in python

Tags: python, json, object, count

I want to count the number of the result JSON objects: how can I do?

I have this function: (the problem is in "for i in r:")

```
import urllib
import json
from classes import ricerca_IMDB

def search_IMDB (titolo):
    sito='http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+titolo

    r=0
    r=json.loads(urllib.urlopen(sito).read())

    i=0
    filmList = []
    try:
        for i in r:
            filmList.append(ricerca_IMDB(r['Search'][i]['Title'], r['Search'][i]['Year'], r['Search'][i]['imdbID']))
    except:
        filmList = []

    return filmList
```

Comment: 'the problem is in'.. but *what* is exactly your problem? Do you get an error? Remove the bare `try` `except` (never a good idea) and tell us what the traceback is.

Answer (score 2):

You've *completely* botched up your type handling. Iterating over a sequence [yields elements](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

```
for i in r['Search']:
  filmList.append(ricerca_IMDB(i['Title'], i['Year'], i['imdbID']))
```